# Unable to pass array of objects via intent extras

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

I'm passing an ArrayList of movie objects from `MainActivity` to a `DetailActivity` via an intent.

```
intent.putExtra(KEY_mFavoriteMovies, mFavoriteMovies);
startActivity(intent);
```

In this other activity, I'm adding additional movie objects.

```
mFavoriteMovies(movie);
```

However, `mFavoriteMovies` in `MainActivity` does not appear to contain the additional movie objects.

Is this behavior expected?

Comment: You can't pass objects simply, you need to have your object class implement Parcelable and then if you are passing one object, use putExtra, and if you are passing array, use putParcelableArrayListExtra

Comment: @the_prole - did you get chance to check my solution(with movie name as String or An Object/Class)? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up. Thanks!

Comment: @JRG You didn't really answer the question. I'm passing an array list through an intent. The answer would be no, the array lists are not the same objects. The passed array list is being rebuilt from a parcel and is an entirely new object. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour because when you modify your array list at `DetailActivity` you are working with a different instance of your movies list.

You can get the changes you make to the list by starting `DetailActivity` with `startActivityForResult` and then sending back the updated list to your `MainActivity`

You would have something like this at your `MainActivity`

```
ArrayList<String> mMovies;
int DETAIL_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
String KEY_FAVORITE_MOVIES = "key-movies";

private void startDetailActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(KEY_FAVORITE_MOVIES, mMovies);
    startActivityForResult(intent, DETAIL_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DETAIL_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mMovies = data.getStringArrayListExtra(KEY_FAVORITE_MOVIES);
    }
}
```

And you will have to send the updated list from the `DetailActivity` with something like this:

```
public void finishDetail() {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(KEY_FAVORITE_MOVIES, mMovies);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach depends on what is movie list ...

- If your movie list is a simple ArrayList of Strings then use
  `putStringArrayListExtra` and `getStringArrayListExtra`.
- If they are Object (separate class) then you should implement
  Parcelable and use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` and
  `getParcelableArrayList`.

If MovieName is an Object/Class then implement `Parcelable`

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MovieName implements Parcelable {

    private String name;

    private String year;

    public MovieName(String name, String year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public MovieName(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        year = in.readString();
    }

    // Creator
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public MovieName createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MovieName(in);
        }

        public MovieName[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MovieName[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(year);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MovieName=[name=" + name + ";year=" + year + "]";
    }
}
```

Inside `MainActivity` when you are about to `startActivity` to go to `DetailActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);

ArrayList<String> movieNames = new ArrayList<String>();
movieNames.add("Star Wars");
movieNames.add("Transporter");
movieNames.add("Need for Speed");
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("MOVIE_NAMES", movieNames);
Log.d("Movie Names", "Writing into intent ... " + movieNames.toString());

ArrayList<MovieName> movieNameList = new ArrayList<MovieName>();
movieNameList.add(new MovieName("Star Wars", "1900"));
movieNameList.add(new MovieName("Transporter", "2000"));
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("movie", movieNameList);
Log.d("MovieName Parcelable", "Writing into intent ... " + movieNameList.toString());

startActivity(intent);
```

Inside `DetailActivity's onCreate`

```
ArrayList<String> movieNames = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("MOVIE_NAMES");
Log.d("Movie Names", "Reading from intent ... " + movieNames.toString());

ArrayList<MovieName> movieNameList = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("movie");
Log.d("MovieName Parcelable", "Reading from intent ... " + movieNameList.toString());
```

Sample Run

```
07-25 16:32:53.108 5264-5264/? D/Movie Names: Writing into intent ... [Star Wars, Transporter, Need for Speed]
07-25 16:32:53.111 5264-5264/? D/MovieName Parcelable: Writing into intent ... [MovieName=[name=Star Wars;year=1900], MovieName=[name=Transporter;year=2000]]

07-25 16:32:53.144 5264-5264/? D/Movie Names: Reading from intent ... [Star Wars, Transporter, Need for Speed]
07-25 16:32:53.145 5264-5264/? D/MovieName Parcelable: Reading from intent ... [MovieName=[name=Star Wars;year=1900], MovieName=[name=Transporter;year=2000]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @JRG answer in order to get updated list in `MainActivity`  you need to start your `DetailActivity` as `startActivityForResult`. This will give you an option to return updated array from `DetailsActivity` using `setResult` to `MainActivity` through `onActivityResult` callback.

Another approach would be to fix it by changing the architecture of an app by separating View part (Activities) from Model (favorite movies).